# What is the probability of winning.

Tags: probability, permutations

$2$ teams of $5$ players each play a game against each other in pairs. Find the probability that no team wins all the games and no team loses all the games.

I tried to solve and determined that there will be $2^{10}$ total possible scenarios. But I am not able to count the scenarios where no team wins all the games and no team loses all the games. Please suggest the way.

It is ambiguous to me.The answer for the problem is 17/32.

Comment: For each game, is there a 50% chance of victory?

Comment: @5xum i think yes as there is nothing  about the strengths of players.

Comment: Is it two teams with 5 players each?

Comment: no they are making pairs.

Comment: So $2$ teams, one with players $a,b,c,d,e$ and the other with $f,g,h,i,j$, then they play $a$ versus $f$, $a$ versus $g$ and so on up to $e$ versus $j$? That makes for a lot more than $2^{10}$ scenarios, you have $25$ games all together, giving you $2^{25}$ outcomes.

Comment: @5xum no they are making pairs so total possible pairs 5*4/2=10.I think!

Comment: @SeemaYadav please explain what you mean by "making pairs". How many players are there in total, how are they playing against each other exactly? What is a "team" here"?

Comment: @5xum i am wrong sorry, there are two teams and in total 10 players.I think it is ambiguous to me.

Comment: Maybe copy the original text of the assignment. The way the game is described now, you have $2^{25}$ scenarios and only $2$ of them involve one team losing all matches and the other winning all matches, giving you a probability of $\frac{2^25 - 2}{2^{25}}=1-2^{-24}$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12613/discussion-between-5xum-and-seema-yadav)